# How to use a global array in C#?

Tags: c#

I am making an `text-based adventure game` for my first little project in C#. In order for my vision to work I need a few arrays that can be accessed in any of the functions. The game will only consist of a single class. And the arrays will need to be able to be changed in any function.

Comment: Declare it at the class scope then... You should really go read some basic tutorial before beginning. Or try things by yourself, you'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: @GrantWinney - You have just won the internet for today, sir :)

Comment: I have read several tutorials but all they cover is constant variables. Or solutions that involve multiple *.cs files and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that C# doesn't really include global variables like in C++, each variable is bound to a scope with only classes being truly global. With that in mind, you could create a "global" variable by doing something similar to this:

```
public static class myGlobalArray
{
    public static int[] thisIsMyGlobalArray { get; set; }
}
```

However, you would be much better served by looking into some other ways of implementing this, so as to not clutter up the global namespace. I'd suggest reading into object-oriented design and learning why C# doesn't really let you make global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your class shoud look something like this:

```
class Something {
    int[] array; //global array, replace type of course
    void function1() {
       array = new int[10]; //let say you declare it here that will be 10 integers in size
    }
    void function2() {
       array[0] = 12; //assing value at index 0 to 12.
    }
}
```

That way you array will be accessible in both functions. However, you must be careful with global stuff, as you can quickly overwrite something.